# targeting iPhoneOS 2.2.1

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, precompiled-headers

I don't believe that I am using any 3.0 specific APIs, but somehow whenever I compile I get a warning "This project uses features only available in iPhone SDK 3.0 and later", and then a bunch of errors.  If I change the Base SDK to 3.0, the warning & errors go away, but then of course I cannot target OS 2.2.1

I see that this is coming from the project_Prefix.pch file, which I assume was created when the XCode initially created the project. I don't see how this file gets included, but I believe this is the source of the problem.  I tried removing it, but then the build won't compile at all.

Do I need to regenerate this file somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me- I was in fact using a 3.0 API.  I had the following:

```
  controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
```

Removing this line fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe the project_Prefix.pch is the file, but if you want to regenerated it just delete it or better yet do a clean on your project.

What are the errors you are getting? That should tell you which 3.0 specific API you are using.